# Streaming debugging in IntelliJ idea (Java)

Tags: java, stream

I want to debug the code that uses stream. When I use stream trace to track the details, an internal error occurs. （IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1）
Main code{

```
String result =
        Stream.of(input.split(""))
            .map(s -> s.charAt(0))
            .sorted()
            .limit(5)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(joining());
    System.out.println(result);
```

}
error: Internal error

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Provide more information.

Comment: I used the stream trace tool when debugging the stream. This error occurred 
Error link：    https://mymarkdownliao.oss-cn-guangzhou.aliyuncs.com/error.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error with your code. I recommend to visit site https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and search for issues similar to yours.